# Accessing cordova.file.directory in AngularJS provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've setup an AngularJS provider and in my provider I am trying to use Cordova Plugin File (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/). I've set it up to grab $cordovaFileProvider, but when I try to reference cordova.file.documentsDirectory I get an error.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.file.documentsDirectory')

Here is an example of the code. I do reference  `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in the index.html file and have setup ionic platform ready.

```
.provider('StateHelpersServ', ['$cordovaFileProvider', function ($cordovaFileProvider){
var prov = {};

prov.getFileData = function(key) {
    // Check the platform
        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS())
        {
            // Check if a file exists in a certain path, directory.
            $cordovaFileProvider.checkFile(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, key + ".json")
                .then(function (success) {
                    console.log("File Exist: " + success);
                    // Read a file
                    $cordovaFileProvider.readAsText(cordova.file.dataDirectory, key + ".json") 
                        .then(function (success) {
                            console.log("ReadFile: " + success)
                            return success;
                            // success
                        }, function (error) {
                            // error
                        });  
                }, function (error) {
                    // File Doesn't Exist
                    console.log(error);
            });
        }
        else if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid())
        {
            // Check if a file exists in a certain path, directory.
            $cordovaFileProvider.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, key + ".json")
                .then(function (success) {
                    console.log("File Exist: " + success);
                    // Read a file
                    $cordovaFileProvider.readAsText(cordova.file.dataDirectory, key + ".json") 
                        .then(function (success) {
                               return success;
                        }, function (error) {
                            // error
                        });  
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });
        }
}
this.getFileData = prov.getFileData;

this.$get = [function() {
    return prov;
}]
}])
```

Comment: When do you call these functions? You may have to wrap the calls to these functions to ensure that the plugin was loaded, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I actually wrapped the ionic platform ready on the functions and unfortunately its still not working. Except, I think you have given me an idea.